# Optimizing SQL statement for a large table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with the following tables:

```
Courses(course varchar(10));
Prerequisite(course varchar(10), prereq varchar(10));
StudentRecord(student varchar(10), course varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY (student, course));
```

Courses holds all the courses in the database. Prerequisite holds all the prerequisites for a given course. And StudentRecord holds all the students who have completed a given course.

I came up with the following query to find courses that a student can take based on the prerequisites he/she has already completed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.student, c.course from StudentRecord s, Courses c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Prerequisite p where p.course = c.course AND
                 p.prereq NOT IN(SELECT course from StudentRecord 
                 WHERE student = s.student)) 
                 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM StudentRecord s2 WHERE 
                 s2.student = s.student AND s2.course = c.course);
```

This query does what it's supposed to and returns a list of courses the student can take based on the prerequisites completed. However, when "StudentRecord" is a large table with over 500+ entries, my query chokes and takes forever to run. Is there an alternative query that runs faster? Can I optimize my current query to run faster? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 500+ rows constitutes a very small table in my book. Especially if there's only 2 columns. 1 million rows would be a large-ish table. Also, are you using mysql or sqlite?

Comment: That's my thought as well. I thought this query could handle 500+ rows, however it cannot. I'm trying to find an alternative way of rewriting the query but can't seem to. I'm using sqlite.

Comment: What indexes have you defined?

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that (Student, Course) in StudentRecord is a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Can you populate this SQL Fiddle with more data? I thought I had enough to cover it, but your query returns no results. (hit cancel if prompted to switch to WebSQL) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/af071/1

Comment: Do you want this query to work for a single student or many students? It's a lot simpler for just 1 student.

Comment: @BobbyScon: In a hurry I typed the wrong statement. In the last not exists, change s.course to c.course. I updated the statement and it seems to work. I need this to work with multiple students. Here's the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/af071/5/0

Comment: Course and Prerequisite need primary keys as well. Those anti-joins are less than ideal from a performance standpoint, but start by defining more keys (which are fancy indexes).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what indexes to create for a query, one way to find out is to look what the database thinks are the best ones.

First, create all possible combinations of indexed columns:

```
CREATE INDEX c_c ON Courses(course);
CREATE INDEX p_c ON Prerequisite(course);
CREATE INDEX p_cp ON Prerequisite(course,prereq);
CREATE INDEX p_p ON Prerequisite(prereq);
CREATE INDEX p_pc ON Prerequisite(prereq,course);
CREATE INDEX sr_s ON StudentRecord(student);
CREATE INDEX sr_sc ON StudentRecord(student,course);
CREATE INDEX sr_c ON StudentRecord(course);
CREATE INDEX sr_cs ON StudentRecord(course,student);
```

Then look at the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for the query:

```
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT DISTINCT s.student.....;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE StudentRecord AS s
0|1|1|SCAN TABLE Courses AS c
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE Prerequisite AS p USING COVERING INDEX p_cp (course=?)
1|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 2
2|0|0|SEARCH TABLE StudentRecord USING COVERING INDEX sr_sc (student=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
3|0|0|SEARCH TABLE StudentRecord AS s2 USING COVERING INDEX sr_cs (course=? AND student=?)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

So you actually need only the `p_cp`, `sr_sc`, and `sr_cs` indexes; drop all the others.

(If you know what you're doing, you could optimizer further. For example, it looks as if neither the DISTINCT nor the `sr_cs` index are necessary.)