# What indexes should i use for my select,DB

Tags: sqlite, select, indexing

this is my [SQLite DB](https://s32.postimg.org/fr2ycrtf9/image.png) . What indexes should i create for the fastest performance of this select and is my select correct ?

```
select way_id,way_pos,lat,lon,tag 
from way_nodes
join nodes using(node_id)
join ways_tags using(way_id) 
where lat < someValue1 
and lat > someValue2 
and lon < someValue3 
and lon > someValue4
order by way_nodes.way_id, way_pos;
```

Now, this select took 40 sec (more then million nodes, 1.4 million ways_nodes , cca 100 000 ways). Im using only select so i dont care if index slow updates,..

Comment: Please show the DB schema.

Comment: There is link in first line. 
https://s32.postimg.org/fr2ycrtf9/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out which indexes are estimated to be actually useful, [use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218773/11654).

Using indexes on `lat` and/or `lon` probably would not help very much.

There is no good way of optimizing a multidimensional interval query except by using an index designed for that, i.e., an [R-tree](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html).

Comment: I was trying all possible index combination and somehow i decrease it to 800 ms but i delete it and now i dont know which indexes worked.

Comment: What if i join tables nodes, ways_nodes,ways_tags  into one with one bigger ? what indexes should i use then ?